# Convert Android Base64 Bitmap and Display on HTML Base64 Image

Tags: java, android, html, bitmap, base64

I develop a custom messenger application which sends message from client(Android) to another client(web). My problem is when I send image file, I encoded it to `Base64` string and then send it to another client. When the recipient client is Android, the app successfully decoded the `Base64` String to bitmap image. But when the recipient client is web app, the web application failed to decode and display it using :

```
<img id="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,3iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...">
```

My Java encode/decode method

```
    public static Bitmap base64StringToBitmap(String base64) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    public static String bitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bmp.compress(format, quality, baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    }
```

I've tried to change the encoding method to `Base64.DEFAULT`, but still the `Base64` String cannot be displayed in HTML using `data:image/jpeg;base64`. Is there any differences between Android `Base64` string and `Base64` string used to display image in HTML? Please suggest me the solution. Thanks

EDIT :

This is the base64 string example generated from my Android application, with padding. I failed to display it on html/web, although it can be displayed fine on Android :

```
3iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8AAABfCAYAAACOTBv1AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAChtJREFU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```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to convert an Android generated BASE64 string to Binary with Javascript and atob function was keep giving me errors. My first guess was like yours to use `URL_SAFE` instead of `DEFAULT`, but none of them worked, then I figure it out that I need to use `Base64.NO_WRAP` method to get it working. 
I tested  `Base64.NO_WRAP` and displaying inline image and IT WORKED!!!!

Hope this save you some nerves, because I did had some till I figure it out how to do it.

So to give the nice answer, change:  `return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.URL_SAFE);` to this:  `return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);`

E

Comment: Ok, let me try this :)

Comment: Still haven't showing in html, but I can save it into image file :)

Comment: That is a workaround, but I'm puzzled why it is not showing in HTML directly, it should. Did you tried it in multiple browsers? Can it be not showing in one specific browser?

Comment: hey i tried it on multiple browser still haven't showing

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this for me it's working fine one two change only Base64.DEFAULT insted of URL_SAFE and image tag alt. just check it.

```
<img height=700px src='data:image/jpg;base64,"+encodeString+"' alt='Embeded Image'/>

public static String bitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bmp.compress(format, quality, baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Can you post your bitmap to Base64 conversion method? I also notice that the length of Base64 String after Android conversion is more longer compared than conversion result using javascript or online converter tools.

Comment: @HafizhHerdi what problem you facing? u had parse base64 with Base64.java file or u had import that file?

Comment: with standard android.util.Base64 package