# Launch Browser to open a file with base64 code

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know if any android APIs are available to open a file which has base64 code in browser?

My server returns some base64 code, that i need to open in a browser without converting as file? Any help on this please

Comment: say the server guy to send the base 64 string in json

Comment: Yes im getting the base64 in JSON only, that base code i need to open in a browser. Any help?

Comment: why do you need..?

Comment: Base64 code user should able to view based on the filetype. if its PDF, the browser should launch the browser and display the file in browser. That is our requirement

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22454184/4973660)